# How to make custom field editable on item level in ME51n tcode?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, badi

My request is to add a custom field to the items in transaction ME5xN.

I found the exit MEREQ001 with a few exit functions - but they don't really help me much as far as I can see.

I found a few BADIs in it, but i don't know well how to use those, and I don't know if they are useful.

Anyway, in the documentation of exit MEREQ001 I found something useful: It says that by creating the table CI_EBANDB and adding fields to it, those fields are added to the table EBAN (so I don't have to do any additional work).

Also, this include structure is included in the display structure MEREQ3211GRID which is used to display the items.

Thus I appended CI_EBANDB and voila: there's my field.

My problem now is that this field is never editable, and i have no idea how to turn it editable.

The table is a CONTROLS: xxx TYPE TABLEVIEW WITH SCREEN 3211.
When I put a breakpoint in a module called in the screen LOOP, it never hits it.

I see that there is only 1 place inside program SAPLMEGUI where this structure is used in the call for LVC_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE, and if I modify properties of that fieldcatalog that results, the output is visible on the screen....

Bottom line: I don't know how to make my field editable.

P.S.
The field should always be editable in transaction ME51N and ME52N.

Answer (score 2):

This is done via customizing. Call transaction spro and then go down the path Materials Management -> Purchasing -> Purchase Requisition -> Define Screen Layout at Document Level and there view the details on the transaction you want to customize.
You need to uncheck the "Display" checkbox for your field.

If you have dedicated customizers in your company ask them for help.